# Nissan qashqal is smoking out of exhaust

Tags: engine

Hi can you help my Nissan is blowing white smoke out of the exhaust for about 10 min when I first use it and when I stop and leave it for a hour then go back and drive it the smoke comes back any ideas cheers Andy

Comment: OP have not been back so this Q&A will keep popping up from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to look for is your oil is it grey/white or the level dropping if it is you might have a blown head gasket if not the head gasket is ok.

Second is the cooliant level is it dropping,or you can see bubbles when the engine is running,if not your head gasket is ok.

It is normal to see some smoke when the engine is cold(more smoke in cold weather)it is mostly water vapor this goes away when the engine gets warmed up.